# Name of coordinates format

Tags: coordinates, degrees-minutes-seconds

There's also a degree, minutes, and seconds format, and one with a decimal number, but what is the name of this format?

What is the name of the GPS format of this lat/long: 35-39-24.720N / 110-26-06.720W

I've seen it in a few different places, but Google Maps doesn't seem to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

DMS is the name of coordinates expressed in degrees, minutes and seconds.

The problem in your coordinates are the separators.

Use: `35°39'24.720"N 110°26'06.720"W`.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=1

Comment: You can also use this format: 35 39 24.720N, 110 26 06.720W